# How to secure user data in ASP.NET Forms Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config

I am making an ASP.NET website and am using `Forms Authentication`; I am using a custom provider for all the security parts (the excellent TinyProviders xml based data providers).

Currently, the users data store (an xml file called Users.xml) contains completely unencrypted data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfXmlUser xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <XmlUser>
    <UserKey>a34cc5b6-a0b9-4a5e-b055-951w799a8607</UserKey>
    <UserName>Bill</UserName>
    <Password>billspassword123</Password>
    <PasswordSalt />
    <Email>bill@contoso.com</Email>
    <PasswordQuestion />
    <PasswordAnswer />
    <CreationDate>2013-03-14T21:46:36.7990912+00:00</CreationDate>
    <LastActivityDate>2013-03-14T21:47:50.3483942+00:00</LastActivityDate>
    <LastLoginDate>2013-03-14T21:47:50.3483942+00:00</LastLoginDate>
    <LastPasswordChangeDate>2013-03-14T21:46:36.7990912+00:00</LastPasswordChangeDate>
    <LastLockoutDate>9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999</LastLockoutDate>
    <IsApproved>true</IsApproved>
    <IsLockedOut>false</IsLockedOut>
    <FailedPasswordAttemptCount>0</FailedPasswordAttemptCount>
  </XmlUser>
</ArrayOfXmlUser>
```

How could I configure the website to do the following:

- Store password hashes (instead of plain text)
- Encrypt all (or at best the email and name) data in the users file

I am looking to do this from my `Web.config` because I am using a binary distribution of TinyProvider.

Here is my `Web.config` so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <profile enabled="true" defaultProvider="XmlProfileProvider">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="XmlProfileProvider"
                  applicationName="SampleWebsite"
                  type="Artem.Web.Security.XmlProfileProvider"/>
        </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="XmlMembershipProvider">
          <providers>
              <clear/>
              <add name="XmlMembershipProvider"
                    applicationName="SampleWebsite"
                    type="Artem.Web.Security.XmlMembershipProvider"
                    minRequiredPasswordLength="1"
                    minRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters="0"
                    requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
                    requiresUniqueEmail="false"
                    passwordFormat="Clear"/>
          </providers>
      </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false" defaultProvider="XmlRoleProvider">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="XmlRoleProvider"
                  applicationName="SampleWebsite"
                  type="Artem.Web.Security.XmlRoleProvider"/>
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for your first question: (Store password hashes (instead of plain text))

The answer is that you change your passwordFormat in your membership provider node from "Clear" to "Hashed" though I don't see a passwordFormat value in your XmlUser node which worries me a bit.  Try it out, and see how it goes.

As to your second question, how do you encrypt the value of the data, I can't think of a way you're going to be able able to do it from the web.config.  Typically you're going to rely on your provider to handle that for you, so if the provider you've chosen doesn't offer that option, I don't know what you're going to be able to do.

Comment: Thanks for the hash tip - I'd heard about it but didn't know where to put it. Thanks you for the information as well, I think I'll edit the provider - because it's open source.